# calculate automatic slippage for pancakeswap exchange like Poocoin.app does

Tags: web3js, nodejs, ethers.js, pancakeswap

I am trying to automate swap on pancakeswap but for some tokens manual slippage percent doesn't help and it fails. I need to set slippage automatically every time based on token requirement. In poocoin.app, it does calculate slippage automatically. I want to do something similar to that. Expecting some experts advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?